# Calling JHipster microservice in third party application

Tags: microservices, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I have created JHipster application with a gateway and few micro services. This jhipster application uses Keycloak for authentication. Now , i want completely different application (third party application written in Java) to integrate with my Jhipster application. This third party application also uses same keycloak authentication server.
This Third party application should be able to consume my micro services.So basically this is backend to backend integration.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this? Will simply using RestTemplate and calling JHipster microservices work?

regards,

Venky

Comment: Yes as long as your app presents a valid token with its requests. It can go through gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Using Keycloak means it will be stateful application. For integration with third parties, microservices should be stateless. So we use Jhipster UAA . Clients with valid OAuth token can call the microservices now.